# How to store only file name not the whole path using c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

In my c# code, I am reading file name to a variable and they could be like C:\users\documetnts\test.bin
but, how can I get rid of the whole path i just want to store file name test.bin not the whole path.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you “reading file name to a variable”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd169920.aspx) Method from the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd170077.aspx) Class in the System.IO Namespace:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\users\documetnts\test.bin";

       Console.WriteLine( Path.GetFileName(path));
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```